# How to avoid repetition on templates in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following code that is repeated on several templates:

```
{% for element in elements %}
    <div class="some-class">
        <div class="another-class">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="{{ entry.user }} avatar" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 100%;" src="{{ entry.avatar_url}}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9" style="some-style">
                    {% if entry.data1 %}<small>{% trans entry.data1 %}</small><br>{% endif %}
                    {% trans entry.data2 %} {% trans entry.data2 %}
                    <br>
                    <small style="some-style">
                        {% blocktrans with timestamp=entry.timestamp|naturaltime %}
                            {{ timestamp }}
                         {% endblocktrans %}
                    </small>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I was wondering what is the best way to avoid repeating this piece of code, I am kind of newbie to Django, and I would really appreciate your help.

**Edit:**
What if I need to pass a content to that template. Is it going to use the same context than the one in the containing file or should I indicate the context in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is easy:

Put this piece of HTML in a file called, say `reusable.html` and then [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) it in other templates.

Like this:

```
<!-- Other HTML -->

... html stuff here

{% include 'reusable.html' %}
```

Now, if you want to pass a parameter to `reusable.html`, you do it like this:

```
`{% include 'reusable.hmtl' with var_a='abc' var_b=123 %}`
```

Comment: Oh, yes. It's so simple. I do this all the time. Keeps me DRY ;)

Comment: what if I need to pass a parameter to that template?, or is the context the same that the one in the file that is contained?

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: one more question, should I reload the `{% load i18n %}` and other loads in the new file or the ones in the containing file are enough?

Comment: Yes, in each template you must include the `{% load ... %}`

Answer (score 1):

Set it up in it's own template, for example `new_template.html` and use `{% include 'new_template.html' %}` wherever you want it

Comment: thank you, though your answer is quite similar to the other one.